# Comparing times in Goroutines

Tags: go, time

I have a test written in Go:

```
func TestThings(t *testing.T) {
    tCh := make(chan int64, 10000)
    ctx, cx := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cx()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    go func(c context.Context) {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(tCh)
        for {
            select {
            case <-c.Done():
                return
            default:
                nt := time.Now()
                tCh <- nt.UnixNano()
            }
        }
    }(ctx)

    go func(c context.Context) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-c.Done():
                return
            default:
                v := <-tCh
                nt := time.Now()
                res := nt.UnixNano() - v
                if res < 0 {
                    t.Errorf("got less than 0; diff: %d now: %d then: %d", res, nt.UnixNano(), v)
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Running this test (sometimes) ends with the result:

```
go test -v -run TestThings ./test
=== RUN   TestThings
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33686100 now: 1639183246323013700 then: 1639183246356699800
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33535000 now: 1639183246323171300 then: 1639183246356706300
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33490200 now: 1639183246323222600 then: 1639183246356712800
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33488300 now: 1639183246323231000 then: 1639183246356719300
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33502600 now: 1639183246323241000 then: 1639183246356743600
    test.go:48: got less than 0; diff: -33551600 now: 1639183246323249100 then: 1639183246356800700
         ...
--- FAIL: TestThings (20.01s)
FAIL
FAIL    test 20.022s
FAIL
```

Why are the times in the receiving Goroutine sometimes before the times in the sending Goroutine?

I understand that clocks are generally hard and unreliable when it comes to computers, but I would expect since these Goroutines are (maybe?) in the same process, but definitely on the same host, that calls to `time.Now()` would return ever increasing values. Or at least not "earlier" ones.

Update:

Something else possibly worth mentioning: I'm running this inside a VSCode devcontainer on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Maybe because you're using `sync.WaitGroup`, you could try without that, just the goroutines.

Comment: This works as expected. Are you sure about the result?

Comment: I would expect this to depend on whether the two goroutines run on two different CPUs on one host *and* whether the clocks on those two CPUs are synchronized. You'd have to be both parallel and unsynchronized (but both are easily envisioned).

Comment: I also can't reproduce this with https://go.dev/play/p/nwd0wSOLxSi - the playground seems to time out incorrectly, but the context timeout works locally.

Comment: Note that the Go playground has GOMAXPROCS=1, so that the two goroutines run sequentially, not in parallel.

Comment: Does this also happen if you change the channel type to `chan time.Time`, the first goroutine to do `tCh <- time.Now()`, and the second goroutine to do `res := time.Since(<-tCh).Nanoseconds()`? That uses [the monotonic clock](https://pkg.go.dev/time#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks) which is supposed to prevent exactly these kinds of problems.

Comment: @Peter No, it does not appear to be happening by passing `time.Time`s. Is there any good way to serialize a `time.Time` and achieve the same result? Or another API I'm missing?

Comment: As explained in the docs linked earlier, serialization intentionally strips the monotonic clock reading, because it is meaningless in another process. Different processes will always have to expect and deal with clock skew, even on the same host.

Comment: Ugh, clearly I failed to read or comprehend that section. Which is a shame. Thank you all for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Peter on the original question referencing the [time package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time), serialization of `time.Time` loses any monotonic information by design:

> Because the monotonic clock reading has no meaning outside the current
> process, the serialized forms generated by `t.GobEncode`, `t.MarshalBinary`,
> `t.MarshalJSON`, and `t.MarshalText` omit the monotonic clock reading, and
> `t.Format` provides no format for it. Similarly, the constructors `time.Date`,
> `time.Parse`, `time.ParseInLocation`, and `time.Unix`, as well as the unmarshalers
> `t.GobDecode`, `t.UnmarshalBinary`. `t.UnmarshalJSON`, and `t.UnmarshalText` always
> create times with no monotonic clock reading.

Changing the code snippet from the original question to pass `time.Time` values between the Goroutines works without issue.